Why running the command with 2 options I got error?
In laravel 10 app I have a command with 2 optional arguments in signature: app:rss-import-by-url-test-command  {defaultCompanyId?} {createPublished?}.
I run the command like:
php artisan   app:rss-import-by-url-test-command  1    1

Where 2 arguments are optional and the second is a bool, not an integer ID.
I need to add 1 more required argument and [reading docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/artisan#options-with-valuesI remade): app:rss-import-by-url-test-command {task_category_id} {--company_id} {--create_published=1).
But running the command with 2 options I get the error:
php artisan   app:rss-import-by-url-test-command  1  --company_id=1  --create_published=1
    The "--company_id" option does not exist.

What is wrong?

ATTEMPT TO FIX ERROR
I modified the signature: app:rss-import-by-url-test-command {task_category_id=} {--company_id=} {--create_published=).
But got the error:
php artisan   app:rss-import-by-url-test-command  1  --company_id=1  --create_published=   
    The "--create_published" option does not exist.

Do not see the difference of syntax of using company_id and create_published?

Since it's expecting a value, you need to add an equals sign to it -- {--company_id=}

Please read ATTEMPT TO FIX ERROR

Remove equal sign from create_published since you not providing value when running

task_category_id does not require the equal sign since it's an argument, not an option.  You'd only use the equal sign if you were assigning a default value. --create_published would need a value on the command line if you're using the flag.

{--create_published=) <- Mismatched braces there too, should be {--create_published=}

@mstdmstd it is very important that you try improving code quality, you are not following the documentation and all the info is in there, try reading it again and check what you have done

First of all run php artisan optimize:clear to clear your local config and cache.
In your attempt to fix error, remove the mismatched braces
{--create_published=) to this {--create_published=}.
When we use this {task_category_id} in a command signature this implies that it is a required argument like this
signature:
protected $signature = 'app:command-name {task_category_id}';
command: php artisan app:command-name 123.
when we use this {--task_category_id} in a command signature this implies that it is boolean option, true if present false if not present. signature:
protected $signature = 'app:command-name {--task_category_id}';
command: php artisan app:command-name --task_category_id.
when we use this {--task_category_id=} in a command signature this implies that expects a value to be passed to it. signature:
protected $signature = 'app:command-name {--task_category_id=}';
command: php artisan app:command-name --task_category_id=123.
You can also declare a default value like this
protected $signature = 'app:command-name {--task_category_id=defaultValue}';
so if it is not provided when you run the command it will use the default value.
